# QtWebDriver for automation testing of Qt application

Tags: qt, webdriver, automated-tests, squish

I faced with task to write test automation framework for Qt desktop application. I found one interesting open source solution - `QtWebDriver`. 
Did some from you work with this tool? 
What can you say about it? Or it'll be better to use commercial solution (e.g. Squish or Testcomplete)

Answer (score 0):

One thing to take into account besides free/commercial aspects is integration with existing (open source) tools.
QtWebdriver integrates with Selenium, which is the de-facto standard for web automation.

This means:

- If you have existing selenium tests you should be able to reuse them
- You can also use selenium+QtWebdriver tests to automate qml/qwidgets
  apps
- You can benefit support from online selenium community as well

Comment: Could you share any examples of testing qml app with QtWebDriver?